# Video capture software that will record long videos (10+ hours)

Tags: gratis, video, windows-10, webcam

Using Windows 10 and a Logitech C270 webcam I've used the

- Camera app (stops after 3 hours)
- Movie Maker (stops after 1 hour)
- VLC (never sure if it works or not! the video playback is amazing but the record isn't so user-friendly)
- Logitech webcam software (recorded 8 hours but it failed to save)

I'm after free software, preferably easy to use but able to change the quality of the video,

Answer (score 4):

There is a very high quality free open source project called [Open Broadcaster Software (OBS)](https://obsproject.com/download).

In the Classic version there is a plugin which stops the recording and saves it and then starts recording again.  The plugin is called [RecordSplitter](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/recording-stopper.19961/page-2) and is available at that link currently.

You configure how long you want it to record before splitting.  There is this very minor drawback though: "You will lose ~3 seconds of footage while the recording stops and restarts."

I suspect that the space you have on your drive would be your only limiting factor for how many hours you could continue recording.

You may also find that the new OBS Studio version will record much longer than your other attempted software.  I have found OBS code to be so good that it may be writing to disk after a certain file size anyway.  It very well may continue to successfully record that single file until you run out of space on the disk, but I don't know that from personal experience.